# How do I set a select only year option in ng2-datepicker?

Tags: angular, ng2-datepicker

I would like to pick only years option in the ng2-datepicker. How do i achieve this?

I could not find an option to disable the dates selection in the module

Comment: check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { DatepickerOptions } from 'ng2-datepicker';
import * as frLocale from 'date-fns/locale/fr';

let options: DatepickerOptions = {
  minYear: 1970,
  maxYear: 2030,
  displayFormat: 'YYYY'
}
```

Add options in your Datepicker function call